# Why does laravel return an object when filtering against values other than 1?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
    $locations = Location::all();
    if ($request->query('customer_id')) {
        return $locations->where('customer_id', $request->query('customer_id'));
    }

    return $locations;
```

that returns an array if `customer_id` is 1 and an object if it's anything else. Where is this inconsistency coming from?
If I call `flatten()` on the result it's always consistent but I can't figure out what causes the difference in results?

Sample output is:
`customer_id=1`

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "customer_id": "1",
    "country": "Bulgaria",
    "city": "Sofia",
    "notes": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-20 08:39:08",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-20 08:39:08",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

And if we get the same but `customer_id=2` (or any other ID):

```
{
  "3": {
    "id": 4,
    "customer_id": "3",
    "country": "Bulgaria",
    "city": "Ruse",
    "notes": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-20 08:39:08",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-20 08:39:08",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = Location::query();

if ($request->query('customer_id')) {
    $query =  $query->where('customer_id', $request-customer_id);
}

//you can use another filter if you want. example
if ($request->query('status')) {
    $query =  $query->where('status', 1);
}

$results = $query->get();
return $results;
```

Comment: This works as intended, with a `->get()` after the `where` method. Can you explain why though?

Comment: `Location::query();`  returns query builder after that you can filter your query. you can add multiple add `where` or `if` so it's good practice to return collection or modal instance after that query filter.  check updated post. check 2nd condition

Answer (score 1):

You have an even better way to do the same thing with eloquent way.

```
 return  Location::
    when($request->query('customer_id'), function($query) use ($request-customer_id) {
              $query->where('customer_id', $request-customer_id);
    })->get()
```